# 4 lsb bits masked due to 4 reserved bits in register--OHCI USB Host implementation- Unrecoverable error

Tags: embedded, usb, host, firmware

I am using an AT91SAM9G45 and am implementing the OHCI for full speed USB host implementation.

I have created the Endpoint Descriptors(ED) and Transfer Descriptors(TD), these are created as structure pointers.

The Host Controller Driver(HCD) is supposed to write the address of the head ED in the HcControlHeadED register. This is a 32 bit register with the last 4 bits reserved and are all 0's. When I create an ED structure pointer, I get a 32-bit address when I write this 32-bit address in the HcControlED register the last 4bits are masked and they become zeros.

How do I resolve this?

When the host controller is given command to start processing of the control ED's I get an unrecoverable error(can say this because the unrecoverable error bit is set then), I am guessing this is because the last 4 bits get masked which changes the pointer address.

How do I fix this problem?

```
typedef struct {
    / FunctionAddress | EndpointNumber | Direction | Speed | sKip | Format
    // MaximumPacketSize
    volatile unsigned int Control;
    // TailP: TDQueueTailPointer

    volatile unsigned int TailP;
    // HeadP: TDQueueHeadPointer Points to the next TD to be processed for 
    volatile unsigned int HeadP;
    // NextED: If nonzero, then this entry points to the next ED on the list
    volatile unsigned int NextEd;
} __attribute__((aligned(16))) OHCIEndpointDescriptor;


OHCIEndpointDescriptor  *ed1;

AT91C_BASE_UHP->UHP_HcControlHeadED=((unsigned int)&ed1);
```

Comment: Is the address of the ED and TD struct in memory supposed to be aligned to 16 bytes?

Comment: @WeatherVane  yes it is, the structure I create is alligned to 16 bytes, then I create pointer to the ED structure, and this pointer I put in the ControlHeadED, when I printf("%x", (unsigned int)&ED_1)........it prints an address whose LSB byte is non zero.

Comment: In which case, the last 4 bits of the address will be 0 anyway.

Comment: It should be but it is not, which is confusing me

Comment: You edited your preceding comment after I replied. In which case, the struct is *not* aligned, *"because the last 4 bits get masked which changes the pointer address"*.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am sorry I kind of lost you there because of me editing. I just re-edited my question, I have included my code there, could you tell me if it looks correct?

Comment: I'm only guessing, but should the alignment attribute be a property of the variable and not the type?

Comment: @WeatherVane It should be a property of the struct type. I figured out the problem, it was with the environment I am using, aligned is a gcc thing, my environment compiler needs 
#pragma data_alignment=16
static OHCIEndpointDescriptor  *ed1;

Comment: Which makes it a property of the variable. As you have answered your own question, I vote up.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for your time!!

Comment: C11 provides full alignment support. You can use [`_Alignas(16)`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.5) alignment specifier

Answer (score 2):

If someone in the future faces this problem, I figured it out, it was with the environment I am using. Alignment is a gcc thing which needs

```
#pragma data_alignment=16 static OHCIEndpointDescriptor *ed1;
```